# converting simple query to cake query?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Actually I have 1 query but I am unable to convert it into CakePHP query format.

```
$result = "select 
             * from esl_userresults
           where 
             esl_userresults.esl_songID = esl_lyrics.id 
             and esl_lyrics.song_name like '%".$esl_keyword."%'" ;
```

When I convert this query into CakePHP it gives an error like:

```
esl_userresults.esl_songID unknown column.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily run direct sql queries on cake using e.g.:
 $this->Picture->query("SELECT * FROM pictures LIMIT 2;"); 
([cake manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/456/query))

Or try something simillar to this:

```
    $result = Esl_Userresults->find('all' , array('conditions' => array(
             "Esl_Userresults.esl_songID" => "Esl_Lyrics.id",
             "Esl_Lyrics.song_name LIKE" => '%'.$esl_keyword.'%'),
              'recursive' => 1)
              );
```

..given that you have properly linked Esl_Userresults and Esl_Lyrics models.

Comment: depends on what kind of relationship EslUserresults & EslLyrics have. is it one-to-many? this is very simple actually. here have a look at the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

Answer (score 0):

Use Containable behaviour rather than recursive. It will give you control down to individual field level. Using it now, at an early stage, will make it second nature later.

If you get confused building the conditions, build it outside the method call.

Try to avoid the use of double quotes except where you need to include escaped or parsed data - they're slower.

```
$conditions = array(
    'EslUserresult.esl_songID' => 'EslLyric.id',
    'EslLyric.song_name LIKE' => '%'.$esl_keyword.'%'
                   )
$this->EslUserresult->contain('EslLyric.text');
$result = $this->EslUserresult->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppModel`'s `query()` function to run SQL query .

ex : `$this->ModelName->query('SELECT * FROM`table`');`
this will return an array of selected records . You can pass simple query as well as complex join query .