# How can I convert this simple query to CakePHP?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting simple query to cake query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092944/converting-simple-query-to-cake-query)

Actually I have 1 query but I am unable to convert it into CakePHP query format.

```
$result = "select 
             * from esl_userresults, esl_lyrics
           where 
             esl_userresults.esl_songID = esl_lyrics.id 
             and esl_lyrics.song_name like '%".$esl_keyword."%'" ;
```

When I convert this query into CakePHP it gives an error like:

```
esl_userresults.esl_songID unknown column.
```

Comment: have you set up the joins in your models correctly?  In fact could you post the model and controller code you're using so we can debug it more easily?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092944/converting-simple-query-to-cake-query

Answer (score -1):

You can execute any query using:

```
<?php 
   function some_controller_name()
   {
     $query_to_execute = 'SELECT * .....';
     $results = $this->ModelName->query($query_to_execute);
     $this->set('results', $results);
   }
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just be careful with the SQL Injection!!!